# XAML designer can't locate resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-designer

I've custom control in shared project ([resource dictionary in shared project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41139017/1997232)).

Everything works fine in run time, xaml designer however throws exception:

> Cannot locate resource 'mycontrol.xaml'.

The problem occurs when loading style for control:

```
public class MyControl: Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        Resources = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/mycontrol.xaml") };
        Style = (Style)Resources["somekey"];
    }
}
```

Why does it works in run-time and doesn't during design time?

I can detect design time, but what to do then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WPF designer seems to have problem when loading xaml files from other projects. Could you try to load the xaml file using this annotation:

```
pack://application:,,,/PROJECTNAMESPACE;component/mycontrol.xaml
```

Comment: If resource is located in the same assembly you don't need to specify the namespace. Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource File Pack URIs

Comment: To my big surprise, this syntax makes designer happy. I was using it prior, but it required assembly which in case of shared project is a problem, but not your problem ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
Uri res = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/mycontrol.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = res });
```

Comment: This is definitely wrong, as `siteoforigin` is *pack URI for a XAML site of origin file, stored in the location from which the executable assembly is launched* ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)), unless you also suggest to store xaml externally.

Comment: aaaaah, my fault ... :-)